# What anime name are these two characters lying in the grass from?

Tags: koijibashi

I have been searching this name for weeks!!
Could you help me out?

[image]

Comment: Please do not delete questions on which people made an effort to provide an answer, even if the answer wasn't what you expected. If the answer is correct and you wish to 'close' the question, mark the answer as correct by clicking on that large green tick mark under the answer's score. If you need any help, please review the [help] for more information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as apart of the phase out of image only id requests. [Meta for further reading](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2736/1587)

Answer (score 11):

It's from a visual novel named [**Koijibashi**](http://vndb.org/v4247), according to the tag on the same image on [Sankaku Channel](https://chan.sankakucomplex.com/post/show/3095057).

[image]

It is released on 2004-August-13 for Windows platform.

**Synopsis** (translated from [Koijibashi's article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%93%E3%81%84%E3%81%98%E3%81%B0%E3%81%97) on Japanese Wikipedia):

> Looking forward to their graduation in March, Tachibana Yuuta, together with his classmates Katakura Hadzuki, Ichinose Ryuu and his childhood friend Konno Nonoka, make a plan to go on a graduation trip together during spring break.
>
> From Yuuta's casual remark, the destination is decided, by Sagara Shiho - Yuuta's cousin who happens to be there, to be a rural town with the suspension bridge named "Koijibashi" (Love Bridge?), which has the legend to tie people's fate together. However, the legend of "Koijibashi" as it is passed down is not your usual pleasant story, and unforeseen mysteries awaits Yuuta and co.